# Spark Kryo Serialization

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, avro, apache-spark-2.0, kryo

We have a Spark Structured Streaming application that consumes from a Kafka topic in Avro format. The payload is part of the `state` object in the `mapGroupWithState` function. Given that we enforce `FULL` compatibility for our Avro schemas, we generally do not face problems when evolving our schemas. However, we have now evolved our schema by adding a nested object and Kryo serialization is failing with the following where `xyz` is the field which is a nested object within `ObjectV1`:

```
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: 020-12-14T19:23:49
Serialization trace:
xyz (x.y.z.ObjectV1)
```

```
Logical Plan:
SerializeFromObject [encodeusingserializer(input[0, java.lang.Object, true], true) AS value#38]
+- MapPartitions <function1>, obj#37: scala.Tuple2
   +- DeserializeToObject decodeusingserializer(cast(value#34 as binary), scala.Option, true), obj#36: scala.Option
      +- SerializeFromObject [encodeusingserializer(input[0, java.lang.Object, true], true) AS value#34]
         +- FlatMapGroupsWithState <function3>, newInstance(class scala.Tuple4), decodeusingserializer(cast(value#23 as binary), scala.Tuple2, true), [_1#29, _2#30, _3#31, _4#32L], [value#23], obj#33: scala.Option, class[value[0]: binary], Update, true, ProcessingTimeTimeout
            +- AppendColumns <function1>, class scala.Tuple2, [StructField(value,BinaryType,true)], decodeusingserializer(cast(value#23 as binary), scala.Tuple2, true), [assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple4, true]))._1 AS _1#29, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple4, true]))._2, true, false) AS _2#30, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple4, true]))._3 AS _3#31, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple4, true]))._4 AS _4#32L]
               +- SerializeFromObject [encodeusingserializer(input[0, java.lang.Object, true], true) AS value#23]
                  +- MapElements <function1>, interface org.apache.spark.sql.Row, [StructField(key,BinaryType,true), StructField(value,BinaryType,true), StructField(topic,StringType,true), StructField(partition,IntegerType,true), StructField(offset,LongType,true), StructField(timestamp,TimestampType,true), StructField(timestampType,IntegerType,true)], obj#22: scala.Tuple2
                     +- DeserializeToObject createexternalrow(key#7, value#8, topic#9.toString, partition#10, offset#11L, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$, ObjectType(class java.sql.Timestamp), toJavaTimestamp, timestamp#12, true, false), timestampType#13, StructField(key,BinaryType,true), StructField(value,BinaryType,true), StructField(topic,StringType,true), StructField(partition,IntegerType,true), StructField(offset,LongType,true), StructField(timestamp,TimestampType,true), StructField(timestampType,IntegerType,true)), obj#21: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
                        +- StreamingExecutionRelation KafkaV2[Subscribe[ext_object_v1]], [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13]
```

The Spark version is 2.4.5. Has anyone come across something similar? Deleting the checkpoint folder resolves this but naturally, we would like to avoid this.

Comment: Which type is xyz? Maybe show some actual (simplified) code.

Comment: xyz is of type Record.